# Laravel - is Artisan:call() synchronous?

Tags: redis, laravel-5, publish-subscribe

I was following the redis pub/sub documentation provided by laravel and created a command to subscribe. However, When I write the subscribe logic in my controller (which is a long running command) using `Aritsan::call()`, the code doesn't execute further as the command keeps waiting for reading a line of published message.

How do I avoid this wait? Is there a way I can achieve this asynchronously?

I tried to queue this job but even `Artisan::queue()` takes similar amount of time. Any advices?

Comment: Did you got any idea for this issue?

Answer (score 5):

Using `Artisan::call()` will execute commands in synchronous mode, while `Artisan::queue()` will execute commands in "queue" mode.

You should see your "queue" mode driver on .env file on `QUEUE_DRIVER` setting. By default that value will be `sync`, so your queue call will be executed synchronously.

Please refer to here for further info about implementing queue https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/queues